# Ruby on Rails API for beginner json response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, api, postman

I am new to ruby on rails. I apologize early if this question might be dumb... but I can't figure this out and the tutorials I've seen is making this simple task confusing. Or I am just not understanding what I am missing or what to do... if a step by step tutorial may help, thanks!

**My task to make a rails api that you can pass JSON to via postman/DH.** 
**The payload will be {"value": "foo"}. A '200 (OK)' Response with payload of {"value":"bar"}**

**No database needed, just a controller that takes in a payload and gives back a       response.**

This is what I do know...

1. What I do know is how to create a rails api by "rails new testrails --api"
2. Then going to my 'gemfile' and installing some kind of json to gems.
3. Then... I mess with the 'route.rb' file in config and the controller in'apps'.
4. I get lost here on what I need to do with the route file and controller...
5. What ever steps come next.

Comment: Please show, what you have tried so far, as described in the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please follow this steps of the SO document: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ruby-on-rails/225/getting-started-with-ruby-on-rails/10887/creating-rails-apis-in-json#t=201703090750238880081

Answer (score 3):

### Step 1: install Rails 5

```
$ gem install rails
```

### Step 2: create an API-only Rails application

```
$ rails new my_app --api
```

### Step 3: integrate rack-cors

Add `gem 'rack-cors'` at the bottom of your `$RAILS_ROOT/Gemfile` (`$RAILS_ROOT` stands for the root directory of your rails app), then

```
$ bundle install
```

Then add these lines to your `$RAILS_ROOT/config/application.rb`, inside the class definition

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :patch, :put, :delete, :options]
  end
end
```

### Step 4: generate a controller

```
$ rails g controller foo
```

Add an action to the `FooController` (in file `$RAILS_ROOT/controllers/foo_controller.rb`)

```
def create
  foo = params[:foo]
  # Do whatever you want with foo
  render json: {value: 'bar'}
end
```

### Step 5: add a route

Modify the file `$RAILS_ROOT/config/routes.rb`, add

```
post '/foo' => 'foo#index'
```

in the block

### Step 6: start rails server

```
$ rails s
```

That's all. Now you can send POST requests to `http://localhost:3000/foo` and see what happens.